# Vim: get time of latest modification of buffer

Tags: vim

Is there a way to get the last modification time of a buffer in Vim?
I'm not interested in `getftime()`, which gets the modification time of the file (on disc).

What I'm looking for is more like `b:changedtick`.

When I undo and redo, I get messages like `1 change; after #39  10:45:00`. Here, `10:45:00` is what I mean by "last modification time of a buffer"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AFAIK, at this point you can only emulate it by recording timestamp (`:h localtime()`) on the events `TextChangedI` and `TextChanged`.

```
aug ChangedTime
  au!
  au TextChangedI,TextChanged * let b:changedtime = localtime()
aug END
```

Depending on your version of Vim these events or `localtime()` may not be available.